# Laptop doesn't boot after subsequnt Ubuntu update

Tags: boot, 16.04, uefi

I have an Asus X75VC laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 currently using UEFI to boot. After running a `dist-upgrade`, my laptop will no longer boot or even enter BIOS reliably.

I was able to get it into BIOS mode a couple times, but changing the boot order and re-installing GRUB did not fix the underlying issue. Finally, I even can't enter BIOS.

I guess it all has something to do with the UEFI boot entry updates.

What can I do to get my system working again?

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that your firmware settings have been damaged. AFAIK, the only way to repair this is from within the firmware setup utility, so you'll have to keep trying until you can enter that tool. (If you can get Ubuntu to boot, you may be able to enter the firmware setup tool by typing `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`.)

Once you're in the firmware setup utility, select the option to restore everything to the defaults. This should do as I've suggested, and with any luck that will clear up the problem. Unfortunately, it's also likely to render Ubuntu unbootable. There are several ways to recover, but the least intrusive (and therefore the least likely to cause a recurrence of the problem) is:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a boot medium from the rEFInd file you download.
3. Boot with the rEFInd boot medium.
4. In rEFInd, boot Ubuntu.
5. In Ubuntu, open a Terminal and type `df /boot/efi`. Note the disk device and partition; for instance, it might be `/dev/sda2`.
6. In the Terminal, type `sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 2 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi -L ubuntu`, changing the `-d` and `-p` options to match the disk device you identified in the previous step. Note that `-l` is a lowercase L, not a digit 1.
7. Reboot and hope it works.

Alternatively, instead of steps #5-6, you could install rEFInd to your hard disk using the PPA or Debian package.

Comment: Thanks, but at the moment I even can't enter BIOS and can't boot anything. First need to at least be able to get into BIOS.

Comment: Another interesting question here - why the problem could appear at all? I didn't do anything non-standard - just did normal update & dist-upgrade. I did this many times before without side effects... Could this indicate some issue with hardware or BIOS?

Comment: Most computers have manual reset procedures that involve DIP switches on the motherboard, removing the battery, holding down the power button, etc. Check your owner's manual and/or contact the manufacturer for help with this, since the procedures tend to be idiosyncratic. Some computers do indeed have buggy firmware that can cause them to be bricked. The last I heard of this was Samsung models from ~3 years ago. I have not heard of ASUS products being affected, but you might just be "lucky" enough to be the first to report such an issue with an ASUS.

Answer (score -1):

Right before you boot, you should see the GRUB bootloader. In GRUB, select advanced options, then select an older kernel.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't show me grub, and I even can't enter BIOS. If I attach usb drive with ubuntu live it also doesn't boot from it. So I suspect smth more serious have happened. The problem is not in new kernel - as I said I could boot it couple of times, after being succesful with entering bios and changing boot order, but I assume it is somthing with BIOS.

Comment: Try re-installing ubuntu on the flash drive, you can also try booting from a live DVD. Once you get booted into a live session, install boot-repair, and follow the steps it gives you.